# Unique Ion-title on each page, same clickable item on all pages

Tags: ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I would like to have a unique ion-title for each page of my ionic app (News, Search etc) but include a settings icon in the toolbar as well that will bring up a modal with a couple different options for the user to interact with. I want to avoid rebuilding the settings icon to keep my code DRY, prevent the unnecessary imports, and preserve separation of concerns.

news.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      News
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-icon (click)='openSettings()' slot='end' name='settings'></ion-icon>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

As expected the page header overwrites the entire app header. I am thinking about building a separate settings icon component, but (I believe) that will require me to import it into every page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: create a new component for settings and you can include it as custom HTML tag to all of your headers i.e. (News, Search etc)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out.

Comment: @VarunSukheja thank you that was the right solution. had to muck around with imports, but got it working.